# The cost price becomes 0 after value of i increases

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I've been trying to execute the following code.. However, I keep getting the same  wrong results and I don't know why!
**MY CODE**

```
int main()
{
        char* sel_items[15]={"apple","ball","keyboard","mouse"};   /*Selling items*/
        float sel_profit[15];         /*Selling Profit*/
        float sel_price[15];          /*Selling Price*/
        float cost_price[15];        /*Original Price*/
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     printf("\n\t\t\tENTER %s PRICE: ",sel_items[i]);
                scanf("%f",sel_price);                           /*Selling Price input here*/
                printf("\n\t\t\tENTER %s SELLING PROFIT :",sel_items[i]);  
                scanf("%f",sel_profit);                          /*Selling Profit input here*/
                cost_price[i]=sel_price[i]*sel_profit[i]/100;        /*Original Price*/
                printf("\n\t\t\t\t\tORIGINAL PRICE : %f",cost_price[i]);
     }
return 0;
}
```

> here is the output of program.

```
                    *ENTER apple PRICE: 50*

                    ENTER apple SELLING PROFIT :50

                                    ORIGINAL PRICE : 25.000000   /*the loop of first item is coorect*/
                    ENTER ball PRICE: 100

                    ENTER ball SELLING PROFIT :20

                                    ORIGINAL PRICE : 0.000000 /*i dont know what happens in the second loop*/
                    ENTER keyboard PRICE: 56

                    ENTER keyboard SELLING PROFIT :3

                                    ORIGINAL PRICE : -0.000000
                    ENTER mouse PRICE: 244

                    ENTER mouse SELLING PROFIT :4

                                    ORIGINAL PRICE : 0.000000*
```

> help me with loop.When the first loop gets executed the conditions become true all the corresponding instructions are executed,But after the second loop i don't know what happens.Do please help..

Comment: You don't index the `sel_profit` in your `scanf()`

Comment: `scanf("%f",sel_price);` ==> `scanf("%f",sel_price+i);` - Same goes for  `sel_profit` two lines later. Honestly, I hope there's more code in your assignment to come, because as-written there is no need for arrays (and thus your bug(s)) in the first place.

Comment: what does it mean/Sorry i'm a beginner

Comment: The code is always reading values to `sel_price[0]` and `sel_profit[0]`, but is calculating the average as `sel_price[i]*sel_profit[i]/100` where (after the first loop iteration) `i` is not zero.   Since `sel_price` and `sel_profit` are uninitialised before the loop,  multiplying values together causes undefined behaviour (after the first loop iteration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sel_price` and `sel_profit` are arrays and in your loop the way you are accessing them is wrong, you should use indexes to access array elements.

Replace this `scanf("%f",sel_price);` with this `scanf("%f",&sel_price[i]);` and the same goes for sel_profit also.

Your for loop should have been like this :-

```
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            printf("\n\t\t\tENTER %s PRICE: ",sel_items[i]);
            scanf("%f",&sel_price[i]);                           /*Selling Price input here*/
            printf("\n\t\t\tENTER %s SELLING PROFIT :",sel_items[i]);  
            scanf("%f",&sel_profit[i]);                          /*Selling Profit input here*/
            cost_price[i]=sel_price[i]*sel_profit[i]/100;        /*Original Price*/
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t\tORIGINAL PRICE : %f",cost_price[i]);
    }
```